# Retrofit2.0 - how to POST image along with some parameters

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit, okhttp

I've been trying to send image file with parameters like `user_id`, using Retrofit, okHttp, Gson, and RxAndroid.

The problem is I always get following error:

> 500 Internal Server Error

I can't upload my file to server. What should I change?

Here's my code.

**HomeActivity.java**

```
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
                .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateTypeAdapter())
                .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
                .create();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();

    UserApi uApi = retrofit.create(UserApi.class);

    File file = new File("sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20131129_123723.jpg");
    RequestBody fileBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), file);

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("user_id", /*some String*/);
    map.put("tweet_id", /*some Numbers*/);
    map.put("tweet_type", /*some Numbers*/);

    this.subscription = uApi.postImage(map, fileBody)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<Tweet>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Tweet tweet) {}

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {}

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
```

**UserApi.java**

```
@Headers("Content-Type: multipart/form-data")
@Multipart
@POST("static/write.json")
public Observable<Tweet> postImage(
       @Part("params") Map map,
       @Part("file\";filename=\"IMG_20131129_123723.jpg") RequestBody file
);
```

I also tried to append headers to the request by myself, but it didn't work and I get the same error as before.

```
    MultipartBody mb = new MultipartBody.Builder("boundary")
                .addPart(Headers.of("Content-Disposition","file; filename=\"IMG_20131129_123723.jpg\"; name=\"IMG_20131129_123723.jpg\""), uploadFile)
                .addPart(paramsBody)
                .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("")
            .post(mb)
            .build();
```

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta3'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta3'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0'
}
```

Could somebody please help me?